# how do I keep the center of my sphere in the actual center

Tags: python, vector, 3d, pygame

this is a tricky question, I made this little program:

```
import pygame as pg
from math import *
import os
import sys
vec2 = pg.math.Vector2
vec3 = pg.math.Vector3

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

width = 1000
height = 800
thickness = 2

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

def p5map(n, start1, stop1, start2, stop2):
    return ((float(n)-start1)/(stop1-start1))*(stop2-start2)+start2

def sphere(radius, point, xrot, yrot, yoffset):
    for i in xrange(point):
        lon = p5map(i, 0, point, -pi, pi)
        for j in xrange(point):
            lat = p5map(j, 0, point, -pi/2, pi/2)
            x = int(radius * sin(lon) * cos(lat)) + width/2
            y = int(radius * sin(lon) * sin(lat)) + height/2 + yoffset
            z = int(radius * cos(lon))
            pos = vec3(x,y,z)
            alpha = int(p5map(z, -radius, radius, 0, 255))
            pos.rotate_x_ip(xrot)
            pos.rotate_y_ip(yrot)
            x = int(pos.x)
            y = int(pos.y)
            screen.set_at((x, y), (0,0,0, alpha))
def run():
    running = True
    point = 100
    radius = 300
    yoffset = 0
    xangle = 0
    yangle = 0
    while running:
        clock.tick(0)
        mouse_pos = vec2(pg.mouse.get_pos())
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    yoffset += -50
                if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    yoffset += 50
                if event.key == pg.K_w:
                    xangle += 10
                    print xangle
                if event.key == pg.K_s:
                    xangle += -10
                    print xangle
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    yangle += 10
                    print yangle
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    yangle += -10
                    print yangle
        pg.display.set_caption("{:.2f}".format(clock.get_fps()))
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        sphere(radius, point, xangle, yangle, yoffset)
        pg.display.flip()

run()
```

you can play around with the keys "wasd" to rotate the sphere and you will rapidly encounter the problem; the sphere doesnt stay centered, it can even go out of the screen!
here is an exemple of how the sphere rotate:
[image: sphere]

and this is how it should:[image: sphere]

see how in the first exemple it isnt centered? how do I fix that so it stay centered?

the sphere doesnt rotate on itself but rather orbit around the 0,0,0 point of my screen. if anyone knows what I am doing wrong I would like to hear it!

another exemple of the sphere rotated(by 120 degrees):[image: sphere]

and how it should be(fixed by hand):[image: sphere]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well nevermind I find a solution, in the sphere function:

```
def sphere(radius, point, xrot, yrot, yoffset):
    for i in xrange(point):
        lon = p5map(i, 0, point, -pi, pi)
        for j in xrange(point):
            lat = p5map(j, 0, point, -pi/2, pi/2)
            x = int(radius * sin(lon) * cos(lat))# + width/2
            y = int(radius * sin(lon) * sin(lat))# + height/2 + yoffset
            z = int(radius * cos(lon))
            pos = vec3(x,y,z)
            alpha = int(p5map(z, -radius, radius, 0, 255))
            pos.rotate_x_ip(xrot)
            pos.rotate_y_ip(yrot)
            x = int(pos.x)
            y = int(pos.y)
            x += width/2
            y += height/2
            screen.set_at((x, y), (0,0,0, alpha))
```

I commented out the + width/2 and + height/2 (which was the offset) and applied the offset after the rotation